# Remmina 1.4.25 on Ubuntu connecting to Windows 11 Remote Machine mix up mouse buttons

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

I am a left handed person, so I set up my local machine (Ubuntu 22.04.2) with the primary button on the right:

[image]

However, it seems like when I use Remmina to connect to a Windows machine, and having it set to using primary button as the Right also there, it doesn't seem to work. [image]

You can see that I am clicking with my left mouse button here, but the Windows remote machine record it as the primary button, while it should be the secondary button instead.

Any suggestions on what I have done wrong? I can switch the button on the Windows machine but then I would have to undo the switch when I use the machine in person. Would prefer not having to do that....